# How to generate csr by giving public key file as input?

Tags: openssl

While looking into google for generating csr using openssl, its provided commands can generate from new rsa:2048 publickey automatically.

My requirement is need to generate csr by giving public key as input.

Anybody suggest me.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Also see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639)

Answer (score 1):

"CSRs are signed using the private key to prevent tampering in transit to the CA. Accordingly, you need the private key to create one."

[How can I create a Certificate Service Request (CSR) from and existing public key of a key pair (assume the private key is in a safe spot elsewhere)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617306/how-can-i-create-a-certificate-service-request-csr-from-and-existing-public-ke)